# Porqué me sale error en sintaxis en el imagen mostrado no puedo identificarlo?

Tags: c#, linq

AQUI TENGO MI CONSULTA DE LINQ

```
   public ComprarBloqueosBusqueda BuscarPorNombre(int? id)
    {
        ComprarBloqueosBusqueda vCOMBLO_Comprar = new ComprarBloqueosBusqueda();
        var result = from BLO in contexto.Bloqueo
                     from EXC in contexto.Excursion
                     where
                       BLO.BloqueosId == 3 &&
                        (from BloExc in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                         where
                            BloExc.BLE_BloqueoID == 3 &&
                         from EXC in contexto.Excursion
                         .GroupBy(e => e.ExcursionesId)
                         .ToList()
                         .Select(eg => new
                         {
                             BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
                             ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
                             EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))
                         })).Contains(new { BLE_ExcursionId = EXC.ExcursionesId });

                    var lComBloquepsNom = result.ToList();
                    foreach (var datos in lComBloquepsNom)
                    {
                        vCOMBLO_Comprar.BloqueosId = datos.ExcursionesId;
                        vCOMBLO_Comprar.excursiones = string.Join(",", result.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre));
                    }
                    return vCOMBLO_Comprar;
                }
```

ESTOS SON MIS TABLAS 
TABLA EXCURSIONES:
ExcursionesId  EXC_Nombre
2                 TANGOL
3                  ESTADIO
4                  VISITA
5                   PLAZA
7                   PAMPA
8                   MADRID
21                  COSTA
22                  PASEO

TABLA Bloqueos:
BloqueosId  BLO_Nombre
1             Visia
2             Paseo
3             Visita2

Tabla BloqueoExcursion:
BloqueoExcursionId BLE_ExcursionId  BLE_BloqueoID 
4                     21                89
5                      4                45
8                       7               23

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,

Tienes un error en el bloque siguiente de código:

```
.Select(eg => new 
{
    BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
    ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
    EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre)),
    })).Contains(new { BLE_ExcursionId = EXC.ExcursionesId 
});
```

Si te fijas, tienes una coma antes de cerrar los `{ }` en el `string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre)),`.

Te debería quedar así:

```
.Select(eg => new 
{
    BloExc.BLE_ExcursionId,
    ExcursionesId = eg.Key,
    EXC_Nombre = string.Join(",", eg.Select(ex => ex.EXC_Nombre))
    })).Contains(new { BLE_ExcursionId = EXC.ExcursionesId 
});
```

Comment: no en el imagen esta como lo hiciste pero sigue saliendo error